# Getting null object reference in onPostExecute in Asynctask?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to display my result in asynctask using webview but i got nullpointExc any help will be appreciated.

```
 @Override
    //Display my result via webview
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { //where i get my result
        setContentView(R.layout.paynamics_layout);
        WebView myweb = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.paynamics_site);
        myweb.loadData(result, "text/html", null); // i got error here
        myweb.canGoBack();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
```

Here is my error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Stacktrace and `doInbackground()` method will help better to know the problem.

Comment: @NileshDeokar pardon , what do you mean thank you

Comment: Your webView (paynamicsite) was not created yet, and you are trying to access it.

Comment: `paynamicsite` is null. check the binding code of the object `paynamicsite`

Comment: i update my code guys please take a look still got the same error thank you.

Comment: why are you calling setContentView in onPostExecute and not onCreate of your activity by the way?

Comment: @ZUNJAE , im trying to call my webview layout to show my asynctask result. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `setContentView`. Use it only in `onCreate();`

You can try any one of the following methods -

- Add WebView in your layout if its not already added!
- Initialize the WebView variable in `onCreate();`
- Keep the WebView's visibility as `View.GONE;`
- loadData for WebView in `OnPostExecute()` & make it Visible by `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Or

- Create another Activity which has a WebView in it;
- Get the Data in onPostExecute();
- Send the Data with Intent to the other Activity & display the same in the WebView.

Comment: thanks for this you give me a great idea thank you bro

Comment: @ShanMichaelReyes You're Welcome :)